# woocommerce get product category id

Tags: php, wordpress, button, hyperlink, woocommerce

I have problem, this very simple question but very important fore me. Thanks fore reading!
My Problem: I'm create presentation page with different category. Each presentation blog have title, description, thumbnail and litel custom menu widget where sub category.
My page Cases&Bag have section Bags information about Bag, title, description and have custom menu widget where link category Women-Bags and Men-Bags. But under this section i need custom buttom with link to just category all Bags. 
And need put Buttom

```
      href="====> Problem heare ( link product category by or or slug ) <===" class="btn btn-default btn-lg manage-btn " role="button">SHOW ALL BAGS</a> 

     Imagen  category-> Cases&Bag/Bags/Women-Bags
        category-> Cases&Bag/Bags/Men-Bags
```

My code now lock like this:

```
    <?php // Get the ID of a given category
//$category_id = get_cat_ID( '62' );
// Get the URL of this category
$category_link = get_category_link( 62 );
?>
<!-- Print a link to this category -->
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-lg manage-btn " role="button" title="SHOW ALL BAGS">SHOW ALL BAGS</a>
```

This not work. It norla? or i have some problem in system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 <?php
    // Get the ID of a given category
    $category_id = get_cat_ID( 'SHOW ALL BAGS' );


    // Get the URL of this category
    $category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );

?>

<!-- Print a link to this category -->
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-lg manage-btn " role="button" title="SHOW ALL BAGS">SHOW ALL BAGS</a>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Category id what i need 62. Fore what place i need put this id?  $category_id = get_cat_ID( 62 );

Comment: <?php   $category_link = get_category_link( 62 ); ?>


<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-lg manage-btn " role="button" title="SHOW ALL BAGS">SHOW ALL BAGS</a>

Comment: Dear Bilal. This not help me. Still link to this Cases & Bags presentation page agan.